# Zsh .. (parent directory completion)

Tags: zsh

In zsh when I type `..` and Press `Tab` I would like it to expand to `../`. At the moment, zsh looks for a directory with two periods in the name and expands to that (such as `.emacs.d`).

Which option affects this kind of behaviour?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564648/zsh-tab-completion-for-cd, the magic command is:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' special-dirs true
```

(The link is about OS X, but I just got it to work on Ubuntu Linux 10.10 as well.)